# Как сделать вот так

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<td>{() => {
  return 'lol';
}}</td>
```

Можно ли как-то сделать подобную конструкцию, чтобы в td подставлялось значение из какого-то внутреннего кода?

Comment: Можно. Вызовите функцию.

Comment: как ее вызвать? в данном примере?

Comment: `<td>{(() => {
  return 'lol';
})()}</td>`

Comment: Читаем про замыкания: https://learn.javascript.ru/closure